# When iterating JSON with Javascript for...in, the final key returned is "remove"

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

This is a strange occurrence to be sure. First off, I'm using Chrome version 23.x and have not tried to reproduce this in other browsers yet.

I receive a JSON array from the server of the form:

**JSON**

```
{
"layout":0,
"caption":"Work History",
"cols":[
   {"field":"company","label":"Company Name","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":2,"list":[]},       {"field":"date_start","label":"From","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":1,"list":[]},
   {"field":"date_end","label":"Until","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":0,"list":[]},
   {"field":"position","label":"Title","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":2,"list":[]},
   {"field":"description","label":"Description","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":0,"list":[]},
   {"field":"project","label":"Project","hidden":false,"order":-1,"validationType":64,"list":[]}
   ]
}
```

Then, I attempt to loop over the cols objects with Javascript"

**Javascript**

```
for (var c in json.cols) {
    console.log("col name: " + c);
}
```

Google Chrome's console prints the following:

**Output**

```
col name: 0
col name: 1
col name: 2
col name: 3
col name: 4
col name: 5
col name: remove
```

There should only be 6 outputs, first of all. Second, where does this final "remove" key come from? Why is it listed?

Comment: `cols` isn't an object, it's an array. Don't use `for...in` with an array, for this reason.

Comment: So, you can't use for...in on an array? Only an object?

Comment: You *can* use it on an array but the results may not be what you expect. [MDN has a good writeup on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: You can (arrays are just objects after all), but you iterate over other properties as well, not only array elements.

Comment: Also note that the problem itself does not have to do anything with JSON. It does not matter *how* you got the data, just what it is.

Comment: I knew it wasn't an issue with the JSON. I just included that as reference to what my data was so it wouldn't be a question. I actually figured it was an issue with for...in, or at least how I was using it. I tried searching this very topic before posting, and no suggestions came up, but that is because I mischaracterized why I was getting this strange result. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `obj.json.cols` is actually an array, not an object, so you should iterate over it with a `for(;;)` loop. I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<json.cols.length; i++) {
    console.log("col name: " + json.cols[i].label);
}
```

Furthermore, there seems to be some script messing with `Array.prototype` on your webpage, as with a `for..in` loop you should *not* be seeing a `remove` property.

Comment: I tested here, the result is the same.

Comment: So your object is not what you think, see http://jsfiddle.net/T2hUX/

Comment: I have an Array.prototype.remove() specified, yes. I guess that explains where it is coming from. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if( json.cols.hasOwnProperty(c) ) { ... }` to wrap your code inside the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

Taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> If you only want to consider properties attached to the object itself,
>   and not its prototypes, use **getOwnPropertyNames** or perform a
>   **hasOwnProperty** check (**propertyIsEnumerable** can also be used).
>
> A for...in loop iterates over the **properties of an object** in an
>   arbitrary order

**JavaScript:**

```
for (var c in json.cols) {
    if( json.cols.hasOwnProperty(c) ) {
      console.log("col name: " + c);
    }
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8DqjS/)**

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please let me know why I was down voted. If you feel the information is incorrect then I will gladly fix it =).

Comment: Probably because there is no reason to use `for...in` on arrays, a normal `for` loop will do just fine (it's faster too).

Comment: I don't see the problem of his implementation with for...in, he used correctly the `hasOwnProperty` how ever, the `for` loop is a faster iterator. I don't think give @Chase a down vote is honest.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree on the relevance of the `for...in` vs a `for`, however, I mainly wanted to specify what the issue actually was, instead of just saying "Change it to a `for` loop". Thanks though @FelixKling, you're probably correct. Since @bfavaretto already has the `for` loop difference, there's little reason for me to add it to my answer, however, it could be beneficial to some, so I'll leave it here for now.